# PostgreSQL reordering or hinting conditions (condition with expesive custom function)

Tags: database, postgresql, query-optimization, user-defined-functions

Short version:

Is there any way how to change order of condition (using custom function) and join operation with another condition in postgreSQL? Postgres will call the function for every record even though the join condition will remove 90% of the records (I tried 8.4 and 9.3 - both are the same)

Long version:
I have table blobs containing cca 2M of records - this table contains key and base64 encoded blob. The blobs are cca 2-4KB big and their inner structure is almost unimportant - I have custom C functions that can extract some information from the blob, mainly its unique ID (used as key) and some sort of customer ID (used for filtering later).

One process is continuously filling this table from external source - it takes the blob and inserts it into the table blobs with its ID as key - something like:

```
INSERT into blobs (blobid,blob) VALUES (getIDfromblob('abcde...'),'abcde...');
```

Now I have clients that do infrequently connect to the database and need to download any new blobs they need to process (according to the customerID from the blob) - every client will get only fraction of the whole table (cca 1:1000). So I have second table called blobdownloads that contains the blobid and customerID. Record in this table means that the client with some customerID have seend blob with some blobID (either did download it or did ignore it). I have custom C function getCustomerIDfromblob that returns the customerID from the blob but it needs to parse the blob and is rather expensive to execute - and it produces some sort of excesive output so I need to use ilike to compare.

There are actualy two problems I am having: First I need to find the blobs that have not been downloaded yet (for specific customerID) - simply saying I need to make a complement. As far as I know there are two reasonable ways - outer join or "if not exists in" which both are not perfect from the theoretical point of view but they do at least work in reasonable manner:

```
SELECT * from blobs LEFT OUTER JOIN blobdownloads USING (blobid) 
WHERE (blobdownloads.customerID is null) or (blobdownloads.customerID != 'customer1')
```

This query should return all blobs that the client with customerID customer1 had not seen at all. The idea is that the client will use this query, filter it by its own customer ID:

```
INSERT into blobdownloads ... where getCustomerIDfromblob(blob) ilike '%customer1%' RETURNING *;
```

and insert these into the blobdownloads table with RETURNING statement and process all the returned blobs. Then it will run the same query with negated condition and without RETURNING:

```
INSERT into blobdownloads ... where not (getCustomerIDfromblob(blob) ilike '%customer1%');
```

And finally to the problem I am encountering. This solution is working and is sending all the blobs it should where it should, there are no collisions and I can force the client to redownload some blobs (delete them in blobdownloads), there are no concurrency issues, no missed blobs, etc... The only problem is that the query is much slower than it should be. The problem is that the query planner is executing the condition with the custom function on the whole table blobs and afterwards it filters the result by the join condition. And as the usual state is that most of the blobs are already downloaded it takes much longer than it could.

The SELECT with outer join without the getCustomerIDfromblob(blob) ilike '%customer1%' condition takes about 5-30 seconds and returns about 1K records (all new blobs since last download). When I add the condition (even without the INSERT) it takes about 5-8 minutes to produce cca 10 records because the engine first executes the custom function on every blob in blobs instead of just filtering  the result. I did try to find some sort of hints but all I could find was posts like this [Order of ANDS in Where clause for greatest performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805863/order-of-ands-in-where-clause-for-greatest-performance) basically saying "the optimizer does it best, do not touch it...". I tried to increase the cost of the function but the execution plan did not change (only the numbers got bigger :-) ). The execution plan looks like this:

```
Nested Loop Anti Join  
Join Filter: (blobs.blobid = blobdownloads.blobid)   Filter: ((blobdownloads.customerID IS NULL) OR (blobdownloads.customerID <> 'customer1'::text))(3493519887,55)
  |--Seq Scan on blobs  
  |   Filter: (getCustomerIDfromBlob(blob) ~~ '%customer1%'(3486446561,93)
  |--Materialize   (71534,92)
    |--Seq Scan on  blobdownloads (41476,61)
```

Note 1:
The functions are declared as IMMUTABLE and there are a functional indices on them and other sensible indices (for all conditions).

Note 2:
I can improve the execution time by changing the ilike to =. Postgres than uses the functional index and the whole query runs under 1 second - but I am not able to remove the extra output from the function, its even more probable that the whole "is it for customer1" condition will be moved to C code as it may need to evaluate more blob inner data (and this is out of my control).

Comment: Why do you think you *need* the function? BTW: tl;dr : please show us the real query.

Comment: The reason I need the function is simple: it uses external library that does the blob parsing and as I said it will maybe do even more in the future and its development is out of my scope... I can not show the real query but the queries in the TL section are real except for table/column names....

Comment: Hiding a(key) field inside a blob violates 1NF. Just saying...

Comment: You are right but this is a special case where I am responsible only for distributing the blobs...

Comment: how many customerids can (co)exist inside a blob?

Comment: For now only one. But maybe it will change in the way that there will not be 1:1 mapping between the ID from blob and client ID (i.e. I will have two clients downloading same blobs for redundancy). But if this happen I plan to use another mapping table for that. Or it will change that the external library will provide function "is the blob for customerID x?". All is in early development and there are some issues that are not 100% set yet.  I actually thought that this will not be the problematic part :-)

Comment: If there is an 1:1 relation: extract the userid from the blob and store it somewhere. (maybe even put it into a domain-table) , and index it.

Comment: This is option I am considering also. But it seems that functional index solves this issue too if I use = but for now I need to compare it with ilike (I would like to avoid that too). But the generic problem I see is: I have query that takes 15 seconds. I add filtering condition and it takes 30times longer because of bad decision of the planner... I could solve it with one PLSQL procedure but I think that thing like this should be solvable with pure SQL...

Answer (score 1):

The join causes **all** customers except customer1 to be combined with the blobs table, which is probably not what you intend:

```
SELECT * from blobs LEFT OUTER JOIN blobdownloads USING (blobid) 
WHERE blobdownloads.customerID is null
   OR blobdownloads.customerID != 'customer1'
   ;
```

---

I *think* your intention was to find all the blobs that were not yet reported to customer1:

```
SELECT * from blobs bl
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT *
   FROM  blobdownloads bd
   WHERE bd.blobid = bl.blobid
   AND bd.customerID = 'customer1'
   );
```

Comment: You are right - its a mistake on my part. But for now I've been testing it only with one customer so it did not matter. I will redo the inner query and see if it helps with the problem

Comment: Mistake fixed, but problem still persists. Your inner query with NOT EXISTS takes about 5 seconds but when I add the outer one with call to the function it takes about 9 minutes