# Order of execution in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Select * from tableA
Where gender=‘m’ and (job title = ‘manager’ or marital_status=‘m’)
```

Which condition will be executed first in the `where` clause?

I.e:

- First it checks gender and if it satisfies then it checks for **`(job title = ‘manager’ or marital_status=‘m’)`**
- Or it executes **`(job title = ‘manager’ or marital_status=‘m’)`** and then check for gender.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL query / clause execution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127932/mysql-query-clause-execution-order)

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of ANDS in Where clause for greatest performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805863/order-of-ands-in-where-clause-for-greatest-performance)

Answer (score 2):

In general the order of evaluation of an expression is not established in SQL.

Database engines are free to evaluate in any order, since they are free to optimize the query. For example:

- If the table has an index on `job_title`, the engine may **FIRST** use `job_title` as "access", and **THEN** use `marital_status` and `gender` as "filtering".
- Alternatively, if the table has an index on `gender`, the engine may **FIRST** use `gender` as "access" and **THEN** use `marital_status` and `job_title` as "filtering".

Do you clearly see the difference between access and filter? All engines need an "access predicate" to retrieve the data, and then they use "filter predicates" to choose which rows are to be returned.

Some times we would like to know the order of the expression evaluation, specifically to short-circuit boolean conditions. This does not work in SQL -- a declarative language -- the way it does in imperative languages (Java, PHP, C#, etc.)

Comment: The real answer is... it depends on what the MySQL query optimizer decides to do.